# Perform some action when a Python module is imported

Tags: python

I want to run a function only if a particular package has been imported, or is later imported.

In pseudo code, this is what I want to do:

```py
if 'some_package' in sys.modules: # The easy part
  do_things_with_some_package()
else:
  # The pseudo code
  somehow_register_callback_for_when_module_imported(
    module_name="some_package",
    callback=do_things_with_some_package,
  )
```

My code is in a library, and *might* be used (by another user) in the same project as `some_package` or might not. When it is, my library might be imported before or after `some_package`.

My code *should not* call `do_things_with_some_package` (because it is slow) unless code consuming my code imports `some_package` at some point.

Is this possible with Python?

Comment: I don't have time to flesh out an answer, but I suspect this might be what you want to look at: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks

Comment: When a path_hook fires, the module being loaded is a "partially initialized module", so if I try and do anything with that module it will error. Were you thinking of something other than registering a path_hook?

Comment: `sys.meta_path` and `sys.path_hooks` are designed to help locate a module with a given path, before the module can be executed and imported. As such they are unsuitable for post-import processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the built-in `__import__` function with a wrapper function that checks if after calling the original `__import__` function, this `some_package` entry appears in `sys.modules` as a key, in which case call `do_things_with_some_package`. This has the benefit of letting the original `__import__` normalize the module name for you in case `some_package` is specified with a package name or with a relative import path.

The example below uses `unittest.mock` in place of `some_package` for easier demonstration:

```
import sys
import builtins

def do_things_with_some_package():
    print('do things with some package')

if 'unittest.mock' in sys.modules:
    print('unittest.mock already imported')
    do_things_with_some_package()
else:
    def __import__(*args, orig_import=__import__, **kwargs):
        not_already_imported = 'unittest.mock' not in sys.modules
        module = orig_import(*args, **kwargs)
        if not_already_imported and 'unittest.mock' in sys.modules:
            print('unittest.mock imported later')
            do_things_with_some_package()
        return module
    builtins.__import__ = __import__
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/SurefootedLeftMainframe

Comment: Great, that works, thanks. Although I see now the docs say overriding __import__ "is strongly discouraged as it is usually simpler to use import hooks", so I'll read up on import-hooks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I ended up using is this:

```py
import sys
from importlib.abc import MetaPathFinder
from importlib.util import find_spec


class FinderWithCallback(MetaPathFinder):
    def __init__(self, module_name, callback):
        self.module_name = module_name
        self.callback = callback

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        if fullname == self.module_name:
            # Temporarily remove this finder from meta_path to avoid recursion
            sys.meta_path.remove(self)

            # Look up the original spec
            spec = find_spec(fullname)

            # Put this finder back into meta_path
            sys.meta_path.insert(0, self)

            if spec is not None:
                # Found the module we're interested in
                # Attach a callback to the loader
                spec.loader.exec_module = self.exec_module_wrapper(
                    spec.loader.exec_module
                )
            return spec

    def exec_module_wrapper(self, original_exec_module):
        # Wrap the original exec_module function
        def exec_module(module):
            original_exec_module(module)
            self.callback()

        return exec_module


def on_import(module_name, callback):
    if module_name in sys.modules:
        callback()
    else:
        sys.meta_path.insert(0, FinderWithCallback(module_name, callback))
```

Which I can use like so:

```py
def on_torch_import():
    import torch

    torch.set_printoptions(precision=7)


on_import("torch", on_torch_import)
```

ChatGPT came up with this.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand 100% the use case, but do you mean something like this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def do_something_with_class(clazz):
...     print('Something with clazz: {}'.format(clazz.__class__.__name__))
...
>>> def print_datetime():
...     print(datetime.datetime.now())
...
>>> if 'datetime' in sys.modules:
...     print_datetime()
... else:
...     import datetime
...     do_something_with_class(clazz=datetime)
...     print_datetime()
...
Something with clazz: module
2023-05-05 09:28:00.972015
```

Edit: Made a better example

Comment: No, that would import a the package when it hasn't been requested.